# JS use name in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have tried many times but nothing works:

In a loop, I want to use the `name` or `id` properties, but they doesn't work.
`var tag[] [number]` does not work. It only prints `undefined` once.

I guess this is an external problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function jat()
            {
                var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("country_events"); 

                for (n=0; n < 4; n++) 
                {   
                    var elem = cls[n];
                    document.write(elem.name);
                }
            }

            function jat2()
            {
                var cls = document.getElementsByTagName("country");

                for (n=0; n < 4; n++) 
                {   
                    var elem = cls[n];
                    document.write(elem.name);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="country_events" name="a"></div>
        <div class="country_events" name="b"></div>
        <div class="country_events" name="c"></div>
        <div class="country_events" name="d"></div>
        <div class="country_events" name="e"></div>

        <country class="country_events" name="a"></country>
        <country class="country_events" name="b"></country>
        <country class="country_events" name="c"></country>
        <country class="country_events" name="d"></country>
        <country class="country_events" name="e"></country>

        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="jat()"></button>
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="jat2()"></button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Both of the functions only print `undefined`.

Comment: So, I don't like the other answers on this page, they seem "obsolete" because I like jquery's ability to do this $("tag[attribute=value]") and I knew there had to be a way to do this in pure js.

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/javascript-function-to-get-dom-elements-by-any-attribute

check that out, it'll give you the ability to select by any attribute value combination.

Answer (score 2):

`div` elements don't have a `name` property, you need to use `elem.getAttribute('name')` to access nonstandard attributes.

HTML doesn't have a `country` tag at all, so they also don't have a `name` property. So again you need to use `getAttribute`.

In general, you should not add custom attributes to HTML elements. Attributes named `data-XXX` are reserved to the user, you should use these.

```
function jat() {
    var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("country_events");

    for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
        var elem = cls[n];
        console.log(elem.getAttribute('name'));
    }
}

function jat2() {
    var cls = document.getElementsByTagName("country");

    for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
        var elem = cls[n];
        console.log(elem.getAttribute('name'));
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P3NeW/3/)

Comment: console.log not worked so changed document.write and result is only a. not more names..just get 1 name and stop.

Comment: it is very impressive info div have not "name"

Comment: what browser are you test? me chrome. and i clicked your demo link.

Comment: What is it needed for? `name` is used for form elements, it's the name that gets sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome. Did you open up the Javascript console?

Comment: id is enough not name. i didn't know it's purpose. and i don't know hot use javascript console, just clicked link and click 1, 2. i mean it's result is nothing.

Comment: If you want to program Javascript, you need to learn how to use the Javascript console. Use `View -> Developer -> Javascript Console`.

Comment: It doesn't work with `document.write` because that overwrites the document. After you write the first name, the elements are removed from the DOM, so you can't get their names any more.

Comment: document.write is just use debug. it is really hot info for me. thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

div tag cannot have **name** attribute, use **id** instead

```
 <div class="country_events" id="a"></div>
 <div class="country_events" id="b"></div>
 <div class="country_events" id="c"></div>
 <div class="country_events" id="d"></div>
 <div class="country_events" id="e"></div>

 document.write(elem.id);
```

If you still want to use name then:

```
elem.getAttribute('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to grab the 'name' attribute you need to use .getAttribute

```
function jat()
            {
                var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("country_events"); 

                for (n=0; n < 4; n++) 
                {   
                    var elem = cls[n];
                    alert(elem.getAttribute("name"));
                }
            }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WsSC/3/)

Comment: it works fine. but edit alert to document.write it works once. but i enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name) it says that JavaScript `element.name` only applies to the following elements, which don't include `div`:

```
<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>,<textarea>
```

Also, don't forget to use `var` in your `for` loop declaration or you are polluting the global namespace with variables:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQRhe/